# Single document collection fetching from flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
Find_Document (coll_name,search_val,return_fld)  {

  var returnval;
  var db = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(coll_name);
  var rec = db.doc(search_val).get().then((value) {
    returnval = value.data()[return_fld];
    print(returnval);
    return returnval;
  });
 
}
```

when I'm tying to use this function, I'm getting null return. If I use `async` and `await`, then its returning error type `'Future<dynamic>'` is not a subtype of type 'String'

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is the expected behavior.  `get()` returns a future that will *asynchronously* provide the requested document.  There is no way to make it block or return immediately - you should indeed use async/await for this, or handle the results in your `then` callback.

Comment: Can you please rephrase this code?  i want to use this dynamically in multiple places to get particular field value

Comment: I'm saying that you should use async/await as you discovered already works.  You should also declare the function async so it can return the data to the caller asynchronouly.  This is pretty standard practice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and patients..  i have done this 
Find_Document (table_name,search_val,return_fld) async  {
  var returnval;
  var db =  await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(table_name);
  var rec = db.doc(search_val).get().then((value) {
    returnval = value.data()[return_fld];
    print(returnval);
    return returnval;
  });
} But am getting the error  type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'